# Elastic Search - Script filter on top of named Inner hits not working

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-painless

I want to retrieve the documents where

- Latest Previous Linkage info (sorted based on modifiedTime desc)'s associationType is OWNER, deleted false

ES Template mapping contains these properties

```
"properties": {
    "previousLinkageInfo": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "associationType": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            },
            "modifiedTime": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "deleted": {
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My document looks like this with `previousLinkageInfo` defined as `nested` object in ES template.

```
{
  "id": "id1",
  "previousLinkageInfo": [
    {
      "associationType": "OWNER",
      "deleted": false,
      "modifiedTime": 123422
    },
    {
      "associationType": "USER",
      "deleted": false,
      "modifiedTime": 123421
    }
  ]
}
```

I break this down into 2 steps

1. Check if I am able to get inner hits as desired - working fine
2. Filter on top of the inner hits that have associationType as OWNED

Step 1:
I tried to get inner hit using the criteria of previousLinkageInfo.deleted false and based on previousLinkageInfo.modifiedTime desc.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "previousLinkageInfo",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "previousLinkageInfo.deleted": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "name": "nested_docs",
                            "size": 1,
                            "sort": [
                                {
                                    "previousLinkageInfo.modifiedTime": {
                                        "order": "desc"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This query is working fine with below result as expected

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.36464313,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_customer_vehicle_association",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.36464313,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "id1",
                    "previousLinkageInfo": [
                        {
                            "associationType": "OWNER",
                            "deleted": false,
                            "modifiedTime": 123424,
                            "associationStartDate": 2,
                            "associationEndDate": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "associationType": "USER",
                            "deleted": false,
                            "modifiedTime": 123423,
                            "associationStartDate": 1,
                            "associationEndDate": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "nested_docs": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "test_customer_vehicle_association",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "previousLinkageInfo",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "modifiedTime": 123424,
                                        "deleted": false,
                                        "associationType": "OWNER",
                                        "associationEndDate": 3,
                                        "associationStartDate": 2
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        123424
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Step 2:
Next step is to check if my inner hit's associationType is OWNER. For this, I tried using script which is not working.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "previousLinkageInfo",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "previousLinkageInfo.deleted": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "inner_hits": {
                            "name": "nested_docs",
                            "size": 1,
                            "sort": [
                                {
                                    "previousLinkageInfo.modifiedTime": {
                                        "order": "desc"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "def latestInnerHit = (params['nested_docs'] != null && params['nested_docs'].hits.hits.length > 0) ? params['nested_docs'].hits.hits[0]['_source'] : null; return latestInnerHit != null && latestInnerHit['associationType'] == 'OWNER';",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways to access the inner hits but params['nested_docs'] is null because of which I am not able to get desired results. Any help will highly be appreciated.